# ASP.NET - Can't access Action in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, post

I am developing a website with ASP.NET. I'm trying to insert a data into a table. My codes are as follows;

`Views/Admin/CreateMisson.cshtml`:

```
@model Paramotor.Models.Entities.Mission
@{
    Layout = "_AdminLayout";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <h2>Add Mission</h2>
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="CreateMission" class="form-control">
        <p>Title:</p>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Title" type="text" required class="form-control" />
        <label>Label:</label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Label" type="text" required class="form-control"></input>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

`AdminController.cs`:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/admin/missions/create")]
public IActionResult CreateMission()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateMission(Mission mission, IFormFile imageFile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Missions.Add(mission);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Admin", "Missions");
    }

    return View(mission);
}
```

When I press the `Add` button, it redirects to `http://localhost:5111/admin/missions/create`. So it doesn't go to Action.

[image]

How can i solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are sending an HTTP request from client when you press the add button.  The server in the controller GET is receiving the request and doing the processing.  The server sends the response which is the POST in the controller where an HTML page is returned to client.  Than client receives the response a loads the webpage with the html.  How is the html received at the client putting the data into the webpage?  All you are showing is the return from the controller.

Comment: I think it's expecting "Mission mission, IFormFile imageFile" and since those args aren't there it can't find a method... you should remove those arguments and bind the objects in the controller's properties.  (and add the proper form fields to bind to...)